# psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL error: bad length

Tags: python, postgresql, ssl, python-3.5, psycopg2

Python 3.5, psycopg2 2.7.4, connects to postgresql database and gets error `psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL error: bad length`
What does this error mean - some SSL certificate is not valid?
Here's traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/db_importer.py", line 278, in <module>
    main()
  File "src/db_importer.py", line 255, in main
    run_process(args, db_params)
  File "src/db_importer.py", line 198, in run_process
    import_csv(cur, schema, table_name, args.raport_data)
  File "src/db_importer.py", line 130, in import_csv
    cur.copy_from(f, '{}.{}'.format(schema, table_name), sep=';', columns=cols)
psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL error: bad length
```

Comment: There was probably lack of space for database, in few hours I should know if it works or not.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? Was this related to the lack of space?

Comment: Yes, it was lack of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After freeing some space the script worked. So tt was lack of space that caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

try 'vacuum full analyze your table' on postgres level, it worked for me. Deadtulips was the issue and 'After freeing some space' might have been autovaccum running